# UWP app icon on taskbar

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp

I have all icon assets sorted out for a UWP app as detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx) except for the icon on the Taskbar. This is because I find the description at the link referred to somewhat long-winded and confusing as to how I should name an icon that should show up on the Taskbar (when the app is running).

I have icon sizes prepared in dimensions of 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 256x256. I named them as recommended as **MyAppName**AppList.targetsize-XX.png where XX is 16, 24, 32, 48 or 256. As I've indicated above, I've no trouble with other icons (on tiles, etc.) but the one on the Taskbar which doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it figured out. I left out the 24x24 icon by mistake, and as it turned out, is the very one required for the Taskbar!

While leaving out the 24x24 icon turned out to be a problem for me, there still remains a potential confusion and the MSDN link doesn't help much. For instance, there is no indication of which of the 5 icon dimensions would be used when. My guess is that these dimensions relate to some adaptive screen sizing but no detail on this. I found the following link more instructive indeed.

**Amended:** As an aside, I found [this link](https://github.com/paulthomson64/uwp-visual-assets) very useful (with demo project, etc) and makes a much better explanation than the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx) provided in the question.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead :( can you provide page title or author or something? having issues with some assets and trying to figure it out.

Comment: @EricLiprandi -- Looks like the website has changed and googling revealed a new one. I have now updated the link.

Comment: That link is also dead now