# Where to set the game icon?

Tags: icons, uwp

I don't know how or where to set the game icon. I see there is the Assets folder, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put in or where to find the information on what to use. While running, the game has no icon on the title bar or in the taskbar.

Comment: You're missing a lot of information here.  To get more positive feedback, try including some more details like what IDE/Language you're using, screenshots or error/warning messages.  The big one here is Language, IDE and project type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag your Icon to Assets folder the double click on **Package.appxmanifest** and you will see the following content, here you can add Icons for Tiles:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use custom icon in the taskbar, We can open the Package.appxmanifestselect in the **Solution Exploer**. And select **Visual Assets** then select **Square 44x44 Logo**, choose one image to set in the **24 x 24 px**.

There is a samilar case you can check with [UWP app icon on taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456302/uwp-app-icon-on-taskbar).

To set the icon to the title bar, we can use [Window.SetTitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx) method to set the image to the title bar. There is a official [Title bar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar), in Scenario2 it extend the view into the title bar.